# disable the Row in ExtJS Grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a checkcolumn as the last column in the grid, i want to disable the row once the checkbox is checked.

```
onCheckcolumnCheckChange: function(checkcolumn,rowIndex,checked){
//disable row code here
}
```

disable means, user should not be able to edit the cells of that particular row.

any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just switching to RowEditing does not solve your problem. What you need to do, regardless the kind of editing, Row or Cell, you have to listen to the [beforeedit event](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/ext/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-beforeedit) and in the listener you need to check if the record is enabled or disabled. If it's disabled then you return false from the listener:

Pseudo code:

```
beforeedit:function(editor, context) {
    var disabled = context.record.get('disabled');
    return !disabled;
}
```

Comment: editing is not my problem, i know that i can handle it in beforeedit event, my problem is how to mark the record as disabled / add the disabled Cls to the entire row once the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Ah so! Take a look at [this example](http://extjs.eu/ext-examples/#grid-styling-rows) if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

try using rowEditing for that

```
var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
    clicksToEdit: 2,
    clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
    listeners: {
        'validateedit': function(editor, e) {},
        'afteredit': function(editor, e) {
            email_field.setReadOnly(true);}
    }
});
```

Check [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/if6) demo.